# Perl Gtk2 CellRendererCombo: get selected item index

Tags: perl, treeview, gtk2

I have Gtk2::TreeView, some of columns are using CellRendererCombo. I have everything work ok, except of I can't get integer index of selected item in CellRendererCombo. **Not a text, but the integer value**.
As a workaround, it could be useful to associate somehow a hash with combo_model, but I don't know how.
Could somebody help me? Trying and googling for a couple of days already.
Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package uform;

use utf8;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Gtk2 -init;
use Glib qw/TRUE FALSE/;
use Glib ':constants';
use Data::Dumper;

use constant col0 => 0;
use constant col1 => 1;
use constant col2 => 2;
use constant colC => 3;

binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');

my $model; my $treeview; my @attr_models;

sub create_window ($$) {
    my ($width,$height)=(shift,shift);
    my $window = Gtk2::Window->new( "toplevel" );
    $window->signal_connect( "destroy", sub { Gtk2->main_quit(); } );
    $window->set_default_size($width,$height);

    my $vbox = Gtk2::VBox->new( 0, 5 );

    $model = Gtk2::ListStore->new(
                    "Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf", #0 pic
                    "Glib::String", #1 product
                    "Glib::String", #2 attr
                    "Gtk2::ListStore"   #combo values list
                  );



    #sample_data
    #some combo lists
    foreach my $d (
    [qw(fast medium slow)],
    [qw(greay orange black white rainbow)],
    [qw(fat with_wholes molded)],
    [qw(long short jeans)]
    )
    {
    my $cmodel = Gtk2::ListStore->new('Glib::String');
    foreach my $str (@$d) {$cmodel->set($cmodel->append,0,$str);}
    push @attr_models,$cmodel;
    }

    #some pixbufs to play with
    my $pixbuf2 = Gtk2::Button->new->render_icon ('gtk-info', 'large-toolbar');



    #add some rows
    my @data = (
    [$pixbuf2,'Shirt',1,$attr_models[0]],
    [$pixbuf2,'Pants',0,$attr_models[0]],
    [$pixbuf2,'Cheese',2,$attr_models[1]],
    [$pixbuf2,'Cola',1,$attr_models[2]],
    [$pixbuf2,'Laptop',0,$attr_models[3]]
    );

    foreach my $st(@data) {
    $st->[2]=$st->[3]->get($st->[3]->iter_nth_child(undef,$st->[2]), 0);
        $model->set( $model->append, 
        0, $st->[0],
        1, $st->[1],
        2, $st->[2],
        3, $st->[3],
    );
    }


#Column0 setup
my $combo_model0 = Gtk2::ListStore->new( 'Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf' );
my $renderer_0 = Gtk2::CellRendererPixbuf->new;

my $column_0 = Gtk2::TreeViewColumn->new_with_attributes(
            "Pic",
            $renderer_0,
            pixbuf => col0
            );



#Column1 setup
my $renderer_1 = Gtk2::CellRendererText->new;
$renderer_1->set( editable => FALSE );

my $column_1 = Gtk2::TreeViewColumn->new_with_attributes(
            "Product",
            $renderer_1,
            text => col1
            );




#Column2 setup
my $renderer_2 = Gtk2::CellRendererCombo->new;
$renderer_2->set(
            editable    => TRUE,
            text_column => 0,
            has_entry   => FALSE
        );

$renderer_2->signal_connect (changed => sub {
    my ($renderer, $str, $iter)=@_;
    print Dumper (@_) . "\n";
    }
);

$renderer_2->signal_connect (edited => 
    sub {
    my ($renderer, $text_path, $new_text) = @_;
        my $combo_model = $renderer->get("model");
    $model->set ($model->get_iter_from_string ($text_path), col2, $new_text);
    }
);

my $column_2 = Gtk2::TreeViewColumn->new_with_attributes(
            "Attr",
            $renderer_2,
            text => col2,
            model => colC
            );







# main program starts
$treeview = Gtk2::TreeView->new( $model );

$treeview->get_selection->set_mode ('single');
$treeview->set_rules_hint( TRUE );

$treeview->append_column( $column_0 );
$treeview->append_column( $column_1 );
$treeview->append_column( $column_2 );


my $sw = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new( undef, undef );
$sw->set_shadow_type( "etched-in" );
$sw->set_policy( "never", "always" );

$sw->add( $treeview );

$vbox->pack_start( $sw, 1, 1, 0 );

$window->add( $vbox );
$window->show_all;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want to convert `$new_text` in the callback for `edited` in the `$renderer_2` combo cell renderer to an index representing its vertical position in the list of choices? Why do you need this feature?

Comment: I'd like to prefer "get current item's index" definition, but yes, you are right.

Comment: I need this because of even string is acceptable way to identify some list's element (eg, hash), this string is visible for the user. That's not good idea: you show pretty formatted info or having no troubles searching vertical index. But not all the same time.
It's very strange that I need to inherite my own subclass from CellRenderer and even use ComboBox just to get one integer.
Also, I'm afraid of lots of trouble searching exact index if some strings aren't unique.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure I understand completely.. but I am not familar with Gtk, I am just trying to help by doing some quick searches on Google. From this, it seems  like the items in a specific combo box should be unique strings? Then could you simply use `$attr_models[$text_path]->get_iter_first` and loop through the model with `$attr_models[$text_path]->iter_next( $iter)` and at each step compare `$attr_models[$text_path]->get_value( $iter )` with `$new_text`. Then you could use a counter to determine the index?

Comment: Understood you, thanks! Yup, decided to go similar way: make arrays, each one per ListStore (for CellRendererCombo), and search index by text each time is `edited`. Looks like there is no any natural way to do this simple thing, except of inheritance and inventing own bicycle. So, very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looks like there isn't any direct answer for this question.
As a **workaround**, you may create array of hashes. Each element corresponds to one TreeView's row and have e.g. fields like *'combo_hash'* and *'current_index'*.
*'current_index'* is self-explained, *'combo_hash'* is array which consists of hashes with some fields like *'text'* and e.g. *'index'* (or other id).
On CellRendererCombo's `'edited'` signal you get current TreeView's index by `$treeview->get_selection()->get_selected_rows()->get_indices()` (it's simple int), and search for selected in CellRendererCombo's `'text'` field through *'combo_hash'* array. Don't forget to store finded *'index'* to *'current_index'*.
This workaround allows non-unique text in different TreeView's rows, but can't handle non-unique text in one CellRendererCombo's ListStore.
**Another workaround** is to inherite subclass from CellRenderer and embed ComboBox, which provides simple integer index. Looks better and have no limitations by non-unique data, but if array of hashes is unavoidable by design (you need to store lots of other info not visible in TreeView), first workaround should be more relevant.